# How i can split column delimited by , in SSAS DAX

Tags: ssas, powerbi, dax, cube

I have GPS coordinates in my column (latitude and longitude separated by `,`) and I am trying to get them into two separate columns.

I am using the below formula but it is not working.

```
= PATHITEM ( SUBSTITUTE ( Fault[lastgps], “,”, “|” ), 1 )
```

1 represents position.

Comment: I did the test, and your formula works for me. Do you have an error message or a blank result?

Comment: getting below error

Comment: the following syntax error occurred during parsing :Invalid token ,Line 1,Offset37,".

Answer (score 0):

Your quotes look weird to me. Does this work?

```
= PATHITEM ( SUBSTITUTE ( Fault[lastgps], ",", "|" ), 1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to handle different lat long sizes and separators:

```
EVALUATE
VAR V_Str = "-23.1232630, -46.68211551"
VAR V_Sep = ", "
VAR V_Pos = FIND(V_Sep,V_Str) 

RETURN
    ROW(
        "Lat",LEFT(V_Str,V_Pos-1),
        "Long",RIGHT(V_Str,LEN(V_Str)-LEN(V_Sep)-V_Pos+1)
    )
```